# Invoking a function within Javascript's 'sort' method

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

While reading over some tutorial code I found that you could invoke a function within Javascript's `sort` method. So for example I have an array filled with integers:

```
var a = [8,6,2,4];
```

To order these integers from greatest to least I created the following:

```
function numSort(num1, num2) {
  if (num1 > num2) {
    return 1;
  } else if (num1 === num2) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

And finally call the sort method to my array

```
a.sort(numSort);
```

There are two things I don't understand. This function in particular only takes two arguments while my array twice that amount. My question are:

1. How does this function iterate through each element despite having only
   two parameters `numm1`, `num2`?
2. How and why are there no arguments
   passed when invoking this function within the `sort` method?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by #2. "no arguments passed" where? Ah, I think I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It gets called repeatedly for pairs of values in the array. It is `sort` that iterates, not the function you wrote. The complete algorithm is [in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11).
2. Arguments are passed when the function in invoked. It is just that it is invoked by the internals of the `sort` function (to which you pass the *function* as an argument), not by your code.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How does this function iterate through each element despite having only two parameters numm1, num2?

It doesn't. `numSort` isn't iterating over anything, it's `sort` that still does the iteration. All that is happening is that `sort` uses your supplied function to tell whether any given two elements are out of order.

> 2. How and why are there no arguments passed when invoking this function within the sort method?

Because it's *not* being invoked. `sort` is being invoked, and the function `numSort` is being passed to it. Your entire function `numSort` is an argument to the function `sort`.

Comment: *This isn't useful in your case as your `numSort` is doing exactly what sort would do by default*. Nope: try `[10, 11, 12, 1, 6, 2, 4].sort()`, vs `[10, 11, 12, 1, 6, 2, 4].sort(numSort)`

Answer (score 0):

you can find a very detailed answer to your question in the following site

[How to Sort Arrays in JavaScript](https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/09/27/how-to-sort-arrays-in-javascript/)